# Roblox Programming Questions, Arqade, Stack-GD or Stack-O?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

My question, which I was just about to post on the Main Site of Arqade, revolves around Ro-Lua.  Otherwise 'Roblox Lua'.

My question was to include some examples and to ask about certain Rotation-axis(es) and how to manipulate them - but it occurred to me, was the question based on *Programming* or *Gaming*?

As Stack Exchange has a network of many many sites, Stack Game Development being one of them, I thought that my question would have suited them.
Or as it had programmatic-al elements in it, it would suit Stack Overflow...
Or... really, should I just ask it here anyway?

Me and many others, as I know of, follow the rule of:
*"If it's related to the game, include it anyway!"*

So... what do you people think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a topic will be off-topic here on Arqade, but **both [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roblox) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox) have tags for Roblox Lua.**

Some SE sites have some overlap, and that's ok. In the *general* case of overlaps like this you will be fine asking the question on whichever site you choose. If you want answers from developers/programmers in general, ask on Stack Overflow. If you want answers strictly from **Game** Developers, ask on Game Development.

My advice? If you're unsure, you should ask the communities on their respective meta-sites first:

- [Meta GameDev](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/)
- [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

We're mostly just gamers here, we can't give much more advice than that.

Comment: Great explanation! I'm thinking of headed to SE-GD. Thanks again!