# Should [roblox-studio] be burned?

Tags: discussion, burnination

There has already been some [discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12269/roblox-programming-questions-arqade-stack-gd-or-stack-o) about Roblox studio being off-topic. If that's the case, why does the tag still exist?

Comment: Is Roblox Studio really off-topic? The previous discussion is about Roblox Lua, which is specifically about the programming element and off-topic on here.

Comment: @antimo Roblox Studio is the tool used to create games on the ROBLOX platform. It's definitely more of a fit for GameDev.SE than here; `roblox` is its own separate tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be nice to 'burninate' that tag.

It still exists because it hasn't been removed.

I believe the standard protocol is to review all the questions with that tag and close them or migrate them to a more appropriate SE site like [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roblox) or [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/roblox). You can do that I think, tho you might not currently have sufficient rep to do anything beyond commenting on those questions.

I believe an SE admin might need to actually 'blacklist' the tag (so that it's not used again in the future). Maybe mods can do that now (or on this SE site) – I'm not sure.

---

In general, asking questions like 'Why hasn't this work been done?' is (mildly) rude – unless you're asking this of your own (paid) employees or people that have otherwise explicitly committed to doing that work voluntarily. I don't think either of those apply to anyone reading your question.

Comment: Questions older than 60 days can't be migrated though, not even by mods...

Comment: @antimo That's a little annoying then, but anyone can always 'manually migrate' an (otherwise) good question.